# Is it possible to host a spigot server and allow PE servers to connect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting, minecraft-spigot

I host a server and want to be able to combine PE users and PC users. I have heard of some software that will allow you to host a minecraft PE server on your computer.

Comment: I have really needed help with this.

Comment: That might be considered spam.

Comment: Sorry first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IT IS NOT POSSIBLE (WITH SPIGOT/OTHER PC SERVERS)**

The software/plugin you probably heard is [Big Brother](https://github.com/shoghicp/BigBrother). It allows you to combine PE and PC users on a single server.

However,

1) it is kind of old, and might not work on your server.

2) It runs on MC:PE server, not MC PC servers.

Comment: K im testing it..

Comment: What is the difference between Big Brother and Redstone Lamp?

Comment: WRONG PLUGIN LINK, sorry. edit: Fixed

Comment: Whats with down vote!??

Comment: @ThomasWilbur not me.

Comment: Where is the jar file?? for my plugins dir?

Comment: "It is not possible with the server you have now". "It runs on MC:PE server, not MC PC servers".

Comment: Is there a way I can have it update like two servers running using the same files.

Comment: No, you can't access the same files with two different programs at the same time.

Comment: Any ideas then that I can do, then running two separate servers.

Comment: There is currently no way to do it, as I stated in my answer. PS. I'm going off to sleep, if this answered your question (you said "Is it possible", I said "It is not"), please hit the green mark on the answer.

Comment: Pls up vote then

Comment: Asking upvotes here aren't really allowed, but I personally think that the question is good, and doesn't deserve a score of -1, so I upvoted it.

Comment: Thx for you help